# change image source with JSON data with javascript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

i trying to change the source of a set of images with JSON data that's been sent over from another page, the JSON data that looks like this:

```
var jsondata = {
    "images": [
    {"src": "images/bgset.jpg"},
    {"src": "images/ar006.png"},
    {"src": "images/br006.png"},
    {"src": "images/cr006.png"},
    {"src": "images/dr006.png"},
    {"src": "images/er001.png"},
    {"src": "images/tr004.png"},
    {"src": "images/tr011.png"}
]}
```

And im trying to change the `src` values of set of images with the class of `.imageset`. im also tiring to work out a way to leave the first one in the JSON data `{"src": "images/bgset.jpg"}`. im lost not knowing how to get around this problem. im not even sure on how to get the values out of this data!

**Update**

thanks for the answers! With the answers i have currently created this:

```
var jsonStr = location.search.substring(1).split('=');
var obj = JSON.parse(unescape(jsonStr[1]));
var jsondata = JSON.parse(obj.jsondata);
var aa = jsondata.images.length;
var ab = jsondata.images.slice(1, aa); // this part removes the first src
var ac = $(".imageset");
// here is the confusion part i found this will go through the set
for( var i = 0; i < aa; i++ ) {              
}
// and this will go through each class
ac.each( function() {
})
```

how do i join both this codes can put one image src per class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here is the working answer for it and once again thanks to @EricG and @donnywals answers couldn't have done it without you guys.

```
var jsonStr = location.search.substring(1).split('=');
var obj = JSON.parse(unescape(jsonStr[1]));
var jsondata = JSON.parse(obj.jsondata);
var aa = jsondata.images.length;
var ab = jsondata.images.slice(1, aa);
var i = 0;
$(".imageset").each(function(i) {
    $(this).attr("src", ab[i++].src);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

jQuery has some really good functions to do what you want. Try looking at them here:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

that should teach how to 'read' JSON with your code.

now for the image source, also use jQuery. You can use

```
$(".imageset").attr("src", jsondata[0].src);
```

for example.

If you want to loop through all images with the imageset class you could just user a for/foreach loop (google it, it's easy)

Comment: with you answer and @EricG answer i mixed it up and try to get the result but im not able to change the src per class it just changes in all images together.

Comment: if you just use $(".imageset") all images with class imageset will change. $(".imageset")[0] would change only the first image with class imageset. ($(".imageset") behaves like an array)

Answer (score 1):

In the case you did mean to skip the first image source, get the relevant sources like this:

```
var relevantSources = jsondata.images.shift(); // All except the first one.
```

Next you'll want to have the image elements with the class .imageset as follows:

```
var relevantImageElements = document.getElementsByClassName(".imageset"); // Or jQuery $(".imagesets");
```

Lastly, just loop through them, assuming the order is already okay.

```
var ln = Math.min( relevantSources.length, relevantImageElements.length;
for( var i = 0; i < ln; i++ ) {
    relevantImageElements[ i ].src = relevantSources[ i ];
}
```

Is this useful?

Comment: I guess I didn't understand your question properly.

Comment: with `.shift()` im am only getting the first source in the array. what i did is `.slice(1, jsondata.images.length)` so i get all except the first

Comment: `relevantImages[ i ].src = relevantSources[ i ];` this part dosent work im not sure why

Comment: Sorry, I'll update the post properly (relevantImages => relevantImageElements)